# c# How to generate a tournament bracket HTML table

Tags: c#, html, css

so i have been stuck with this issue for 3 weeks now and i couldn't for the life of me figure it out.
what im trying to do is to get this kind of output/presentation using tables.

http://www.esl-world.net/masters/season6/hanover/sc2/playoffs/rankings/

it's a bracketing system for a kickball tournament. 
so my model looks like this

```
public class Match{
public int id {get;set;}
public int teamid1 {get;set;}
public int teamid2 {get;set;}
public int roundnumber {get;set;}
public int winner {get;set;}
}
```

so, what i'm doing now is i loop through the rounds first say, there are for rounds i would do this

```
for(int r = 1; r < bracketRounds; r++){
   for(m = 1; m < roundMatches +1; m++){
      matchGroup = "<tr><td>" + team1 + "</td></tr>"
                 + "<tr><td>vs</td></tr>"
                 + "<tr><td>" + team2 + "</td></tr>";
   }
}
```

but then this would just produce a 1 column table that will show all the matches. was wondering if anyone could help / point me to the right direction as to how i should approach this so that i can insert the subsequent rows to the right of the first row so it'll have a bracket like ouput.

thanks!

Comment: looking at their html... they are using one big table for everything.  You could also do it by having multiple one column tables each in their own div and then use css to position them where you want them.

Comment: great! art work, logic is very fantastic. i think you should first calculate and retrieve the information of winner in each match and then properly apply logic for `colspan` number in your column. Looking at the reference site. the table design is maintained with respect to colspan only.

Comment: That's actually the first thing I did and I wouldn't ask if I found one. Thanks for the heads up tho!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I have tested the code for 2, 3, and 4 Round Tournaments. The outputs for a 2-Round and 3-Round tournament are shown here:

[image]

---

[image]

---

I have used the same model that you provided to define a `Match`. I have added a `Tournament` class to generate test data.

**Match.cs - The class containing the models**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace tournament
{
    public class Match
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int teamid1 { get; set; }
        public int teamid2 { get; set; }
        public int roundnumber { get; set; }
        public int winner { get; set; }

        public Match(int id, int teamid1, int teamid2, int roundnumber, int winner)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.teamid1 = teamid1;
            this.teamid2 = teamid2;
            this.roundnumber = roundnumber;
            this.winner = winner;
        }
    }

    public class Tournament
    {
        public SortedList<int, SortedList<int, Match>> TournamentRoundMatches { get; private set; }
        public Match ThirdPlaceMatch { get; private set; }

        public Tournament(int rounds)
        {
            this.TournamentRoundMatches = new SortedList<int, SortedList<int, Match>>();
            this.GenerateTournamentResults(rounds);
            if (rounds > 1)
            {
                this.GenerateThirdPlaceResult(rounds);
            }
        }

        public void AddMatch(Match m)
        {
            if (this.TournamentRoundMatches.ContainsKey(m.roundnumber))
            {
                if (!this.TournamentRoundMatches[m.roundnumber].ContainsKey(m.id))
                {
                    this.TournamentRoundMatches[m.roundnumber].Add(m.id, m);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.TournamentRoundMatches.Add(m.roundnumber, new SortedList<int, Match>());
                this.TournamentRoundMatches[m.roundnumber].Add(m.id, m);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateTournamentResults(int rounds)
        {
            Random WinnerRandomizer = new Random();

            for (int round = 1, match_id = 1; round <= rounds; round++)
            {
                int matches_in_round = 1 << (rounds - round);
                for (int round_match = 1; round_match <= matches_in_round; round_match++, match_id++)
                {
                    int team1_id;
                    int team2_id;
                    int winner;
                    if (round == 1)
                    {
                        team1_id = (match_id * 2) - 1;
                        team2_id = (match_id * 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int match1 = (match_id - (matches_in_round * 2) + (round_match - 1));
                        int match2 = match1 + 1;
                        team1_id = this.TournamentRoundMatches[round - 1][match1].winner;
                        team2_id = this.TournamentRoundMatches[round - 1][match2].winner;
                    }
                    winner = (WinnerRandomizer.Next(1, 3) == 1) ? team1_id : team2_id;
                    this.AddMatch(new Match(match_id, team1_id, team2_id, round, winner));
                }
            }
        }

        private void GenerateThirdPlaceResult(int rounds)
        {
            Random WinnerRandomizer = new Random();
            int semifinal_matchid1 = this.TournamentRoundMatches[rounds - 1].Keys.ElementAt(0);
            int semifinal_matchid2 = this.TournamentRoundMatches[rounds - 1].Keys.ElementAt(1);
            Match semifinal_1 = this.TournamentRoundMatches[rounds - 1][semifinal_matchid1];
            Match semifinal_2 = this.TournamentRoundMatches[rounds - 1][semifinal_matchid2];
            int semifinal_loser1 = (semifinal_1.winner == semifinal_1.teamid1) ? semifinal_1.teamid2 : semifinal_1.teamid1;
            int semifinal_loser2 = (semifinal_2.winner == semifinal_2.teamid1) ? semifinal_2.teamid2 : semifinal_2.teamid1;
            int third_place_winner = (WinnerRandomizer.Next(1, 3) == 1) ? semifinal_loser1 : semifinal_loser2;
            this.ThirdPlaceMatch = new Match((1 << rounds) + 1, semifinal_loser1, semifinal_loser2, 1, third_place_winner);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have generated the raw HTML dynamically using the static method `GenerateHTMLResultsTable`. This was done using only `<table>` without any need for `<div>` blocks.

**Program.cs - The static Program class that initializes test data and generates the HTML**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace tournament
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GenerateHTMLResultsTable(Tournament tournament)
        {
            int match_white_span;
            int match_span;
            int position_in_match_span;
            int column_stagger_offset;
            int effective_row;
            int col_match_num;
            int cumulative_matches;
            int effective_match_id;
            int rounds = tournament.TournamentRoundMatches.Count;
            int teams = 1 << rounds;
            int max_rows = teams << 1;
            StringBuilder HTMLTable = new StringBuilder();

            HTMLTable.AppendLine("<style type=\"text/css\">");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .thd {background: rgb(220,220,220); font: bold 10pt Arial; text-align: center;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .team {color: white; background: rgb(100,100,100); font: bold 10pt Arial; border-right: solid 2px black;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .winner {color: white; background: rgb(60,60,60); font: bold 10pt Arial;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .vs {font: bold 7pt Arial; border-right: solid 2px black;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    td, th {padding: 3px 15px; border-right: dotted 2px rgb(200,200,200); text-align: right;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    h1 {font: bold 14pt Arial; margin-top: 24pt;}");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("</style>");

            HTMLTable.AppendLine("<h1>Tournament Results</h1>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
            for (int row = 0; row <= max_rows; row++)
            {
                cumulative_matches = 0;
                HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
                for (int col = 1; col <= rounds + 1; col++)
                {
                    match_span = 1 << (col + 1);
                    match_white_span = (1 << col) - 1;
                    column_stagger_offset = match_white_span >> 1;
                    if (row == 0)
                    {
                        if (col <= rounds)
                        {
                            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <th class=\"thd\">Round " + col + "</th>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <th class=\"thd\">Winner</th>");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row == 1)
                    {
                        HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\" rowspan=\"" + (match_white_span - column_stagger_offset) + "\">&nbsp;</td>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        effective_row = row + column_stagger_offset;
                        if (col <= rounds)
                        {
                            position_in_match_span = effective_row % match_span;
                            position_in_match_span = (position_in_match_span == 0) ? match_span : position_in_match_span;
                            col_match_num = (effective_row / match_span) + ((position_in_match_span < match_span) ? 1 : 0);
                            effective_match_id = cumulative_matches + col_match_num;
                            if ((position_in_match_span == 1) && (effective_row % match_span == position_in_match_span))
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\" rowspan=\"" + match_white_span + "\">&nbsp;</td>");
                            }
                            else if ((position_in_match_span == (match_span >> 1)) && (effective_row % match_span == position_in_match_span))
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"team\">Team " + tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[col][effective_match_id].teamid1 + "</td>");
                            }
                            else if ((position_in_match_span == ((match_span >> 1) + 1)) && (effective_row % match_span == position_in_match_span))
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"vs\" rowspan=\"" + match_white_span + "\">VS</td>");
                            }
                            else if ((position_in_match_span == match_span) && (effective_row % match_span == 0))
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"team\">Team " + tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[col][effective_match_id].teamid2 + "</td>");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (row == column_stagger_offset + 2)
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"winner\">Team " + tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[rounds][cumulative_matches].winner + "</td>");
                            }
                            else if (row == column_stagger_offset + 3)
                            {
                                HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\" rowspan=\"" + (match_white_span - column_stagger_offset) + "\">&nbsp;</td>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (col <= rounds)
                    {
                        cumulative_matches += tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[col].Count;
                    }
                }
                HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            }
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("</table>");

            HTMLTable.AppendLine("<h1>Third Place Results</h1>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <th class=\"thd\">Round 1</th>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <th class=\"thd\">Third Place</th>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\">&nbsp;</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\" rowspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"team\">Team " + tournament.ThirdPlaceMatch.teamid1 + "</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"vs\">VS</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"winner\">Team " + tournament.ThirdPlaceMatch.winner + "</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"team\">Team " + tournament.ThirdPlaceMatch.teamid2 + "</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"white_span\">&nbsp;</td>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("    </tr>");
            HTMLTable.AppendLine("</table>");
            return HTMLTable.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tournament Test3RoundTournament = new Tournament(3);
            Tournament Test2RoundTournament = new Tournament(2);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Tournament\results.html", GenerateHTMLResultsTable(Test2RoundTournament));
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Tournament\results.html", GenerateHTMLResultsTable(Test3RoundTournament));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Explanation of Parameters Used to Generate the HTML Table**

[image]

As you can see, the `column_stagger_offset` is the amount by which each column is shifted up to align them the way they are supposed to. The `effective_row` is essentially where the particular table cell would have been had there been no vertical shift. Knowing the `effective_row` and the `position_in_match_span` helps determine what needs to be shown in that particuar cell (blank, team1, team2, or vs.).

As you've noticed, I am iterating over the columns one row at a time. That seems most natural considering that HTML tables are also constructed that way, i.e. create row, add cells ... create row, add cels ... and so on.

Comment: wow thank you so much!!!
sorry for the late reply, i was kinda stumped earlier. anyway, have a few questions, it seems that you're processing per column and not per row? also im trying to understand what the stagger_offset and effective_row is used for?

Comment: @gdubs I'll explain those sometime later today. I don't believe it'll be very clear if I just explain in words. I'll edit the answer with some pictures explaining what these variables mean.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement this using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table by dynamically adding table rows and table cells.

### Class File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Matches
/// </summary>

    public class Rounds
    {
        public int RoundNumber{get;set;}
        public List<Match> Matches{get;set;}

        public Rounds(int number, List<Match> matches)
        {
            this.RoundNumber = number;
            this.Matches = matches;
        }
    }

    public class Match
    {
        public int MatchId{get;set;}
        public Team Team1{get;set;}
        public Team Team2 {get; set;}
        public Team WinningTeam { get; set; }

        public Match(int id, Team t1, Team t2) :this (id, t1, t2, null)
        {

        }

        public Match(int id, Team t1, Team t2, Team t3)
        {
            this.MatchId = id;
            this.Team1 = t1;
            this.Team2 = t2;
            this.WinningTeam = t3;
        }
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public int TeamId {get;set;}
        public string TeamName {get;set;}

        public Team(int id, string name)
        {
            this.TeamId = id;
            this.TeamName = name;
        }
    }
```

### .aspx.cs file - We need to add a div control in .aspx file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Rounds> rounds = new List<Rounds>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowRoundMatchesUsingTable();
    }

    private List<Rounds> GetRoundMatchesDetails()
    {
        List<Team> teamList = new List<Team>();
        teamList.Add(new Team(1, "Arcenal"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(2, "Barsa"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(3, "Manchester"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(4, "Black Burn"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(5, "Ferrari"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(6, "Adidas"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(7, "Reebock"));
        teamList.Add(new Team(8, "Nike"));

        List<Match> matchList1 = new List<Match>();
        matchList1.Add(new Match(1, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Arcenal"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Barsa")));
        matchList1.Add(new Match(1, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Manchester"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Black Burn")));
        matchList1.Add(new Match(1, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Ferrari"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Adidas")));
        matchList1.Add(new Match(1, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Reebock"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Nike")));

        List<Match> matchList2 = new List<Match>();
        matchList2.Add(new Match(2, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Arcenal"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Manchester")));
        matchList2.Add(new Match(2, teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Adidas"), teamList.Find(lst => lst.TeamName == "Nike")));

        List<Rounds> rounds = new List<Rounds>();

        rounds.Add(new Rounds(1, matchList1));
        rounds.Add(new Rounds(2, matchList2));

        return rounds;
    }

    private void ShowRoundMatchesUsingTable()
    {
        IEnumerable<Rounds> roundsList = GetRoundMatchesDetails();

        if (roundsList == null || roundsList.Count() == 0) return;

        Table tbl = new Table();

        TableRow trHeaderRow = new TableRow();
        TableRow trDetailRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell tcDetails = new TableCell();

        foreach (Rounds round in roundsList)
        {
            TableHeaderCell th = new TableHeaderCell();
            th.Text = "Round : " + round.RoundNumber ;
            trHeaderRow.Cells.Add(th);

            if (round.Matches != null && round.Matches.Count > 0)
            {
                tcDetails = new TableCell();
                trDetailRow.Cells.Add(tcDetails);
            }

            foreach (Match m in round.Matches)
            {
                Table dtlTable = new Table();
                tcDetails.Controls.Add(dtlTable);

                TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = m.Team1.TeamName;
                tr1.Cells.Add(tc);
                dtlTable.Rows.Add(tr1);

                tr1 = new TableRow();
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = "Vs";
                tr1.Cells.Add(tc);
                dtlTable.Rows.Add(tr1);

                tr1 = new TableRow();
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = m.Team2.TeamName;
                tr1.Cells.Add(tc);
                dtlTable.Rows.Add(tr1);
            }
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(trHeaderRow);
        tbl.Rows.Add(trDetailRow);
        div.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. interesting, i've never thought of that! let me see if i can replicate this on mvc!

Comment: @Shamjith Haridasan I don't think your `ShowRoundMatchesUsingTable()` will align the matches as shown on the page that the OP linked to. It'll also not follow the bracketing system as intended by the OP. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yeah, that's kind of what the road block for me atm. it seems like creating a separate class for MVC is the way to go, but aligning it the way i want it to is proving to be difficult at the moment..