# For loop to create extra columns

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, html-table

This code displays a basic tree structure bracket, I am trying to complete it to now do the following:-

1. Where it shows:

   style="border-right:2px solid #000;"

   I am trying to use this border for every row, but this script does not create the rows in between the teams/seeds to define the border, I am trying to show border-right for every row from every TEAM 1 to TEAM 2 etc and for all other rounds TEAM 1 to TEAM 2 etc.
2. PHP error reporting is returning this following line has a undefined offset also after the `} ELSE {`?

   ```
   $line[$i] .= '<td align="center" style="border-right:2px solid #000;" colspan="2">vs</td>';
   ```

   3.

   ```
           $array = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4', 'Team 5', 'Team 6', 'Team 7', 'Team 8');
           $j = count($array);
           for ($a=0; pow(2, $a) <= $j; $a++) //determine the highest power of 2 that will go into the array count
           {
               $y[$a] = 1;
               $maxpower = $a;
           }
           for ($i=1; $i < $j*2; $i++)
           {
               if($i % 2 != 0) //odd number rows for teams
               {
                   $line[$i] = '<td class="pf_title_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">' . $array[($i-1)/2] . '</td>
                                <td class="pf_content_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>';
               }
               else
               {

                   for($b=0; $b<=$maxpower; $b++)
                   {

                       $round = $b+1;              
                       $line2[$b] = ($b < $maxpower ? "<th colspan='2'>Round {$round}</th>" : "<th colspan='2'>Winner</th>");

                       if($i % pow(2, $b) == 0) //even rows for future rounds. every 2^1 rows for first winner, 2^2 for second winner, 2^3 for third and so on.
                       {
                           if($i % pow(2, $b+1) != 0) //does not divide by the next power of 2, so this must be the last available cell
                           {
                               $line[$i] .= '<td class="pf_title_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">Team '.$b.'_'.($y[$b]++).'</td>
                                             <td class="pf_content_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>';
                           }
                           else //the input will be added in a future round
                           {
                               $line[$i] .= '<td align="center" style="border-right:2px solid #000;" colspan="2">vs.</td>';
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }   

           //name="WIN'.$b.'_'.($y[$b]++).'                

           eval ("\$content = \"".$this->gettemplate("table_header")."\";");

           $content.="<thead><tr>";

           foreach($line2 as $col) 
           {
               $content.=$col;
           }

           $content.="</tr></thead>";

           foreach($line as $row)
           {
               $content.="<tbody><tr>{$row}</tr></tbody>";
           }

           eval ("\$content.= \"".$this->gettemplate("table_footer")."\";");
   ```

Any help on this very appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure you're using powers right; 2^1=2; 2^2=4; 2^3=8 and so on... don't you want multiples instead?

Comment: it seems to work ok.. just want to be able to add those borders?

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732347/c-sharp-how-to-generate-a-tournament-bracket-html-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758843/php-tournament-bracket

Answer (score 0):

You aren't constructing your table correctly; you were putting a tbody tag around every row, invaliding your HTML. This works for me:

```
<?php
$array = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4', 'Team 5', 'Team 6', 'Team 7', 'Team 8');
            $j = count($array);
            for ($a=0; pow(2, $a) <= $j; $a++) //determine the highest power of 2 that will go into the array count
            {
                $y[$a] = 1;
                $maxpower = $a;
            }
            for ($i=1; $i < $j*2; $i++)
            {
                if($i % 2 != 0) //odd number rows for teams
                {
                    $line[$i] = '<td class="pf_title_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">' . $array[($i-1)/2] . '</td>'.PHP_EOL.'<td class="pf_content_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
                else
                {

                    for($b=0; $b<=$maxpower; $b++)
                    {

                        $round = $b+1;
                        $line2[$b] = $b < $maxpower ? "<th colspan='2'>Round {$round}</th>".PHP_EOL : "<th colspan='2'>Winner</th>".PHP_EOL;

                        if($i % pow(2, $b) == 0) //even rows for future rounds. every 2^1 rows for first winner, 2^2 for second winner, 2^3 for third and so on.
                        {
                            if($i % pow(2, $b+1) != 0) //does not divide by the next power of 2, so this must be the last available cell
                            {
                                $line[$i] .= '<td class="pf_title_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">Team '.$b.'_'.($y[$b]++).'</td>'.PHP_EOL.'<td class="pf_content_bg" style="border-right:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>';
                            }
                            else //the input will be added in a future round
                            {
                                $line[$i] .= '<td align="center" style="border-right:2px solid #000;" colspan="2">vs.</td>'.PHP_EOL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //name="WIN'.$b.'_'.($y[$b]++).'

            //eval ("\$content = \"".$this->gettemplate("table_header")."\";");

            $content="<table><thead><tr>";

            foreach($line2 as $col)
            {
                $content.=$col;
            }

            $content.="</tr></thead><tbody>".PHP_EOL;

            foreach($line as $row)
            {
                $content.="<tr>{$row}</tr>".PHP_EOL;
            }

            $content.='</tbody></table>';

            //eval ("\$content.= \"".$this->gettemplate("table_footer")."\";");
            echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for the update but I still wish to add border-right style to every row in between every team 1 vs team 2, I am not sure how to go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean as they have border-rights for me. If you need to find a `<td>` then add classes to the ones you put in to pinpoint where it gets generated, i.e. `<td class="i_mod_2_not_zero">`

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have conflicting css?

Comment: Basically the script produces this, take a look at the picture:- http://team-x1.co.uk/script.png                                                    you can see border-right is not implemented for each row in between every team 1 vs team 2. Can you understand what I am trying to do? thanks guys!

Comment: I don't. Can you circle where the border is to go? Team 1 vs. Team 2 to me means the first column which does have lines running all the way down.

Comment: the script looks like this:- http://team-x1.co.uk/script.png and I want it to look like this:- http://team-x1.co.uk/script2.png

Comment: I would set up a recursive function that keep track of level so it can calculate the gap needed between teams. That way you can create a function to write the section to a multidimensional array and then you have another function to translate that to an HTML table.